# Creating LUCI ipk package

Tags: openwrt, luci

I tried to create package of for example luci-app-adblock but got stuck in it.

So I made:

```
 cd ~/openwrt
 ./scripts/feeds update -a
 ./scripts/feeds install -ap luci
 make oldconfig
 make -j$1 tools/install
 make -j$1 toolchain/install
 make V=s ~/openwrt/package/feeds/luci/luci-app-adblock/compile
```

Last command give me error:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/vagrant/openwrt'
make[1]: *** 
No rule to make target '/home/vagrant/openwrt/package/feeds/luci/luci-app-adblock/compile'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/vagrant/openwrt'
/home/vagrant/openwrt/include/toplevel.mk:216: recipe for target '/home/vagrant/openwrt/package/feeds/luci/luci-app-adblock/compile' failed
make: *** [/home/vagrant/openwrt/package/feeds/luci/luci-app-adblock/compile] 
Error 2
```

How can I create standalone luci package?

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple, after toolchain was installed need to do

```
make toolchain/install
make package/<package_name>/compile
```

in my case it was

```
make package/luci-app-adblock/compile
```

Package file will be found in **bin** path